# How to pass Whole paragraph to Google Translate API v2?

Tags: android, google-api, translate

I have used translate api v2 for translation of simple word or text.but now i want to translate whole paragraph. i have tried to pass whole paragraph but it didn't worked.

this is my code:

```
public String requestTranslation( String txt, String src, String dst ) 
    {
        if(txt.length()>0)
        {
            String request = requestURL + requestKey + requestSrc + src + requestDst + dst + requestTxt;   
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                request += URLEncoder.encode( txt, "UTF-8" );
                URL url = new URL( request );
                URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
                connection.setConnectTimeout(0);
                connection.connect();

                InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader( connection.getInputStream(), "UTF-8" );
                BufferedReader in =  new BufferedReader( inputStreamReader, 512 );

                String line;
                while ( ( line = in.readLine() ) != null ) {
                    sb.append( line );
                }
                in.close();

                JSONObject jObj;
                JSONArray data = null;

                    jObj = new JSONObject(sb.toString());
                    jObj = jObj.getJSONObject("data");
                    data = jObj.getJSONArray("translations");

                    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);
                        // Storing each json item in variable
                        txt = c.getString("translatedText");
                    } 
                    return txt;
                //return sb.toString();
            } 
            catch ( Exception e ) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return null;
    }
```

i have passed text "How are you?" and its working perfectly. But when i pass whole paragraph then it gets exception from http connection.

Paragraph is like:

"A wiki enables communities to write documents collaboratively, using a simple markup language and a web browser. A single page in a wiki website is referred to as a "wiki page", while the entire collection of pages, which are usually well interconnected by hyperlinks, is "the wiki". A wiki is essentially a database for creating, browsing, and searching through information. A wiki allows non-linear, evolving, complex and networked text, argument and interaction."

so Basically my question is how can i pass paragraph to google translate api v2 and get translated response?? i have googled several posts but couldn't find any that works for me.

Hope you guys understand what i want.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this i have broken paragraph in to multiple string with predefined range. so its working fine with it. it has just one problem that it breaks the word when we use predefined range so it can't be translated. otherwise it works:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    if(Message.length()>200)
                    {
                        //sb.append(requestTranslation(Message,"en", "gu"));
                        for(int i=0;i<Message.length();)
                        {
                            if(i+200<=Message.length())
                            {
                                sb.append(requestTranslation(Message.substring(i, i+200),"en", "gu"));
                                i+=200;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                sb.append(requestTranslation(Message.substring(i, Message.length()),"en", "gu"));
                                i+=200;
                            }
                        }
                        Log.d("Translated Text:- ", sb.toString());
                        Message = sb.toString();
                    }
```